Laplace transform of special function
The Confluent hypergeometric function of first kind (aka Kummer's function) is defined as
$${\mathbf{M}}\left(a,b,z\right)=\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(a\right)\Gamma\left(b-a%
\right)}\int_{0}^{1}e^{zt}t^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-a-1}\,\mathrm{d}t$$
I know from NIST-DLMF integral results (equation 13.10.4) that
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-zt}t^{b-1}{\mathbf{M}}\left(a,b,t\right)\,\mathrm{d}t=z^{%
-b}\left(1-\frac{1}{z}\right)^{-a}, \Re\{b\} >0,\Re\{z\} > 1$$
and I want to calculate the integral
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{st}e^{-kt}t^{b-1}{\mathbf{M}}\left(a,b,t\right)\,\mathrm{d}t$$
by comparing and substitution, I calculated the results as
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{st}e^{-kt}t^{b-1}{\mathbf{M}}\left(a,b,t\right)\,\mathrm{d}t = (s-k+1)^{-a} (k-s)^{a-b} , \Re\{b\}>0, \Re\{k-s\}>1$$
However when I plug the integral into Wolfram Mathematica 13.2, I get the following result
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{st}e^{-kt}t^{b-1}{\mathbf{M}}\left(a,b,t\right)\,\mathrm{d}t = \cos (\pi  a) (-k+s+1)^{-a} (k-s)^{a-b}\text{ if }, \Re\{b\}>0$$
How is this possible?!? What is going on? Did I made a mistake?
There is also link to this same question on Mathematica stack exchange cause it is probable that I don't know how to use Mathematica properly.
Thanks in advance
====================Edit=========================
I also include the wolfram output here to bring the possibility of making error on my part as low as possible.


Ohh, thanks for the comment! You are right, $\cos (a\pi)$ can be written like that. But also there is no conditions for convergence!

Likely it should be $(k-s-1)^{-a}(k-s)^{a-b}$ instead of $(s-k+1)^{-a} (k-s)^{a-b}$ as shown by this substitution in the first integral. Then, this with $\cos(\pi a)=\Re((-1)^{-a})$ makes the result you typed for the Mathematica output equal to it, after distributing the negative sign. However, there is also an extra factor of $\Gamma(b)$ in the wolfram output. Was it in the DLMF?

Yes indeed, you are right there is $\Gamma(b)$ in Wolfram solution however to be consistent with NIST-DLMF I omitted it (cause there is $M(a,b,t)$ and the normalized version $\mathbf{M}(a,b,t)$ which differ in one $\Gamma(b)$ factor). Thanks for the solution, however there is no convergence condition in the Wolfram solution! How to deduce that?

Also now that I thought about the solution, we have $(-1)^{-a}$ as the multiplicative factor, why to use its real part $\Re{(-1)^{-a}}$ instead? I did not understand how to include the real part instead! Could you please explain it?
